# Mozilla ThunderBird not Working with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: email, email-client

I just formatted my system completely and installed Ubuntu OS 14.04 on it. I have been using Ubuntu via VMWARE on my windows 8.1 but this is the first time am using it as a complete standalone OS. I am still setting things up here and i usually use Microsoft Outlook at my workplace to receive mails via Microsoft Exchange.

I discovered Mozilla Thunderbird doesnt offer such option, what can i do to recieve mails via Microsoft Exchange on my Ubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: In Outlook, under Accounts, look for settings for incoming mail (IMAP or POP) and outgoing mail (SMTP). In Thunderbird, create an account with these settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use thunderbird as a mail client for an exchange server you will have to enable IMAP on the the exchange server.
If you do not want to use IMAP, or if you can not persuade your system administrator to enable IMAP on the exchange server, you will have to either:

- use [DAVMAIL](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) with thunderbird
- use Evolution with the MAPI plugin as a mail client

Comment: Further options are: 
 - (Evolution mail client with the _evolution-ews, evolution-mapi or evolution-exchange_ plugin)
 - [MExInt](https://github.com/guderkar/MExInt) Thunderbird plugin
 - [ExQuilla](https://exquilla.zendesk.com/hc/en-us) Thunderbird plugin

Comment: @Tapper My experience with the solutions that involve the Exchange Web Services (EWS) have not been satisfactory. Even though from the ones you recommend I have only tried the evolution plug-ins. But if you go this way, why not use the mapi plugin.